# Symfony2 - Manage dynamic rights

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7

I'm working on a tool in which Administrator will be able to create group and assign rights/roles according to the existing entities. i.e, for a post entity, user can create / edit / delete / update ...

How to show all this possibilities for each entities ?

To sum up, I would like to have a grid with all possible rights whithout hardcoding it. This grid must be able to update when I add a new feature/entity.

Have you got an idea how to solve it ? I have look at ACL and Voters but I'm not sure this is a good way to do it.

I don't know if my explanation are understandable, let me know if it's not the case.

**Edit 1 :**

Actually I'm using FOSUserBundle and PUGXMultipleUser, to manage my user and group.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a "please do this for me" so to get your started, why not take a look at the [FOS User Bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html)? To narrow it down further to what you require, please take a look at [FOS User Bundle Groups](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/groups.html)

Comment: Hi ! First thank you for your reply !
I'm already using FOSUserBundle with PuUGXMultipleUser. 

I can easily add user and group, but I don't really know how to manage rights, I can Hardcode rights, but it's not what I want, cause it's will be more difficult to maintain code...

I don't really know if you understand what I mean ?